# How does an instance method declaration outside a class work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Well, the title of the question may seem improper, but I want to ask how does the following code actually work?

```
class Klass < Struct.new(:x, :y, :z)
end

public
def foo
        bar
end

def inspect
        "Can't override inspect -> #{self.class}"
end

private
def bar
        [x, y, z]
end

def baz
        send(:class)
end

obj = Klass.new(1, 2, 3)

p obj.foo            # => [1, 2, 3]
p obj                # => #<struct Klass x=1, y=2, z=3>
p Klass.ancestors    # => [Klass, #<Class:0x0000563835a45600>, Struct, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Now, this looks like a very bad practice. But how does this actually work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods defined outside any class are added to the `Object` class, which is one of `Struct` ancestors (that is, `Struct` inherits all `Object` methods).

Try this in a new irb session:

```
self.class
#=> Object

self.respond_to?(:foo)
#=> false

def foo
  "foo"
end
#=> :foo

self.respond_to?(:foo)
#=> true
```

In the provided example, you create an instance of `Klass` (which include `Struct` and `Object` in its ancestors chain), so when a new `Klass` instance is created, it includes all `Object`'s methods, including the new `foo` method.